# reset div data-time with bfh-timepicker bootstrap class

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, reset, timepicker, custom-data-attribute

I need to have a field in a form that allows me to enter hours and minutes. With bootstrap it is easy to use the bfh-timepicker class. However, the difficulty I am experiencing is to reset the field in such a way that the value entered disappears and the value indicated in the placeholder reappears.

```
<div class="bfh-timepicker" data-mode="24h" data-placeholder="Orario inizio" placeholder="Orario inizio" id="datepicker" data-time=""></div> 

<a onclick="resetta();" style="cursor: pointer;" id="resettaorarioinizio">Cancella</a>
```

```js
function resetta() {
  $("#datepicker").val();   or //.val("");  
}
```

In this way the inserted time does not reset, but is updated according to the current time. I then tried to work on the data-time element:

```
$("#datepicker").data("time").val("");
// or    
$("#datepicker").attr("data-time").val("");    
// or    
$("#datepicker").setAttribute("data-time").val("");
```

The problem, however, also through `data()`, `attr()`, and `setAttribute()` is not solved. I would therefore need some suggestions to resolve this situation.

thank you very much to anyone who can help me

Comment: Try using `.val('')`. None of your examples are doing that

Comment: hi @RoryMcCrossan thank you for editing. also using .val('') the inserted time is updated according to the current time...